# To show an operator is an isomorphism

Tags: vector-space-isomorphism

Given that $X$ is a Hilbert space. $T$ is a bounded linear operator where $T:X\rightarrow X$. It is also given that there exists $\theta$ where $0<\theta<1$ such that $|<Tx,x>|\leq\theta$ for all $x\in X$ and $\|x\|\leq 1$.

I am supposed to show that $I-T$ is an isomorphism from $X$ onto itself.

My idea is to show that there exists constants $c,C$ such that $0<c\leq C<\infty$ and $c\|x\|\leq \|(I-T)x\|\leq C\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$ and then $I-T$ is an isomorphism.

Now, $\|(I-T)x\|=\|x-Tx\|\leq\|x\|+\|Tx\|\leq\|x\|+C'\|x\|=(1+C')\|x\|$

The existence of the $C'$ is due to the fact that $T$ is bounded linear. So the right side is more or less done. But how to prove the left side? How do I make use of the $\theta$ given in the question?

Another attempt...

$\|x-Tx\|^{2}=<x-Tx><x-Tx>=<x,x>-2<Tx,x>+<Tx,Tx>$

Since $<x,x>$ and $<Tx,Tx>$ are both non-negative.

$\|x-Tx\|^{2}\geq <x,x>-2<Tx,x>$ ...

Comment: Can you show that $I-T$ is injective?

Comment: By definition, we can also prove that $T$ is an isomorphism by proving that $T$ is a bijection and both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous. But I didn't try this method...

Comment: My suggestion is along the lines of, start with the easy part (or at least, start by identifying whether part of the proposition is easier than another part).  So you've shown $I-T$ is bounded (continuous), and a start on getting the other part of the inequality, $c||x|| \le ||(I-T)x||$, is to think about injectivity.

Comment: I am curious about the $\theta$ given in the question and it only applies to $x$ in the unit ball. Does that mean I have to map $X$ to the unit ball first?

Comment: Can you elaborate more that how is $c\|x\|\leq \|(I-T)x\|$ related to the injectivity?

Comment: Yes, you asked about the role of $\theta$, and my suggestion is related to that.  Although $\theta$ is mentioned in reference to vectors in the unit ball of $X$, by a normalization argument it can be considered in connection with all vectors in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let's check that $I-T$ is bounded below.  For $||x|| = 1$,
$$
||x - T x|| \ge |\langle x - Tx , x \rangle| \ge ||x||^2 - |\langle Tx , x \rangle| \ge 1 - \theta.
$$

Since $I - T$ is bounded below, conclude that it has closed range.

At this point, you still need to show that $I - T$ has dense range, and hence is surjective.

Comment: I think I understand your method above, an operator is bounded below iff it has closed range and injective. It need not be surjective am I right? Any suggestion on the surjective or injective?

Comment: You have to show $I - T$ has dense range.   This is equivalent to something about $I - T^*$.  What can you say about $I - T^*$?

Comment: For your “edit”, why is it that your first inequality holds?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

In your second attempt you have $||x-Tx||^{2} \geq \theta ||x||^{2}$ if $||x|| \leq 1$. Just apply this with x changed to $x/||x||$ to see that the same inequality holds for all x.

Comment: Oh my god...that is brilliant! Thanks Kavi!

Comment: But unfortunately it doesnt work because the inequality I obtained does not hold actually haha